# Classic ASP And Window Width

Tags: asp-classic, width

I need to know the user's browser width within a Classic ASP page.  Initially I thought that perhaps a JavaScript cookie would do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.cookie = "this_page_width = " + window.innerWidth;
</script>  

<%
window_width = CInt(Request.Cookies("this_page_width"))
%>
```

Of course, the problem here is that the cookie gets set after the page has been delivered, so this only works on refresh.

Is there any way that Classic ASP can get the browser's width so that I can make a decision within the page before sending it?

Cheers -

george

Comment: You have to be told by the client, so at least one postback is required. Perhaps you could alter your flow so a user lands on a page that sets the cookie with the width, but does a redirect (e.g. meta refresh, javascript, etc) to itself [if cookie not set] or a page hosting your main script.

Answer (score 0):

As with any page, you can send information to the server via GET, POST (you can use a hidden Iframe for this) or make an AJAX call.